# Can I send a markdown file or markdown text to create a page in Notion?

Tags: notion-api

Notion has a feature (https://www.notion.so/help/import-data-into-notion) where you can create a page or page content by importing from various sources including a markdown file.

Is there a way to do this using the API? I know I can append page content, but the API requires me specify each block. This seems pretty onerous!

If the API can't do it, are there any services that I can use?

Comment: I'm also looking for something similar!